# How do I push an object in Actionscript3

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, collision

I'm developing a simple flash game where my player pushes barrels off of a boat to win the game. I've coded for movement and defined most objects, but when I add collision properties, I lose the ability to move the player with the keyboard. Here is the code:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main_Character extends MovieClip
{
    var vx:int;
    var vy:int;

    public function Main_Character()
    {
        init();
    }
    function init():void{
        vx = 0;
        vy = 0;

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }
    function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
        {
            vx = -5;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            vx = 5;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            vy = -5;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            vy = 5;
        }
    }
    function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || 
            event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
            {
                vx = 0;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || 
                event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
            {
                vy = 0;
            }
    }
    function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        player1.x += vx;
        player1.y += vy;

        if (player1.x > 530)
        {
            player1.x = 530;
        }
        else if (player1.x < 0)
        {
            player1.x = 0;
        }
        else if (player1.y < 0)
        {
            player1.y = 0;
        }
        else if (player1.y > 515)
        {
            player1.y = 515;
        }
        else if (player1.hitTestObject(water1))
        {
            player1.x -= vx;
            player1.y -= vy;
        }
             Collision.block(barrel1, player1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to post the code of your `Collision` class or at least of the `block` function in it.

Comment: Here is my error: C:\Users\Carl\Desktop\proejct\Main_Character.as, Line 83 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method block through a reference with static type Class.

How is this fixed? How do I create a collision class? I think that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So the reason you're getting an error of `possibly undefined method` is because your `Collision` class most likely doesn't exist.  I think I found the site you copied code from and they did not include their `Collision` class code, so you'll have to make your own.

But for a basic understanding of how to do this, you might first want to add simple collision functionality in your `player` class.  You can do this by modifying your key event handlers and your `onEnterFrame` function by creating another variable in your `player` class, let's say, `var speed:int = 5`, and modify your `onKeyDown` handler to use that instead of `5` for your movement speed.

Then, in your `onEnterFrame` handler you need to replace the line `Collision.block(barrel1, player1);` with the following:

```
// see if player hit a barrel.  If so, decrease movement speed slightly.
else if (player.hitTestObject(barrel1)) {
    speed = 3;
}
else {
    speed = 5;
}
```

But this alone is not quite enough.  After that, you'll need to make sure your `barrel` class is capable of being pushed around by the player.  You should probably make a `public` variable in its class, such as `public var barrelSpeed:int = 0`, as well as a `public var barrelDirection:int = 1` (to control the direction of the barrel's movement).

That way, you can then modify the `barrelSpeed` and `barrelDirection` variables whenever the player hits a barrel.

---

So to summarize, your `player.as` should have the following just before its constructor:

```
var speed:int = 5;
```

And your `barrel.as` should have the following before its constructor:

```
public var barrelSpeed:int = 0;
public var barrelDirection:int = 1;
```

Modify the `barrel`'s `onEnterFrame` function like so:

```
this.x += (barrelSpeed * barrelDirection);
// for realism, you can also tween barrel's y value to simulate a slight bounce.
```

Then, your `player.as` should have the following at the end of its `onEnterFrame` function:

```
// see if player hit a barrel.  If so, decrease movement speed slightly.
else if (player.hitTestObject(barrel1)) {
    speed = 3;
    barrel1.barrelSpeed = 3;

    // if vx is positive, barrelDirection is positive; otherwise it's negative.
    barrel1.barrelDirection = (this.vx > 0) ? 1 : -1;
}
else {
    speed = 5;
    barrel1.barrelSpeed = 0;
}
```

And your `player`'s `onKeyDown` function should look like this:

```
function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        vx = -(speed);
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        vx = (speed);
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        vy = -5;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        vy = 5;
    }
}
```

Now, you'll also need to change a few things to get interaction with  multiple barrels to work.  For  a great tutorial on that, here's some code that shows basically the same thing except with towers attacking enemies:

http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-create-a-tower-defense-game-in-as3-part-4/

Essentially, you'll want to create an array in your main.fla containing all the barrels and loop through them to see if you collide with them.  I recommend starting by getting a single barrel to work and go from there.

Good luck, and let me know if it works out.